# protecting a ShadowRoot element

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom

I am working on a web extension that adds a custom overlay element to any website. naturally I don't want the websites CSS and JavaScript to interfere with my custom element, nor do I want to influence the appearance of any websites in any way other than with my overlay.

So naturally I turn to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM). I soon learn that I can't simply attach my shadow DOM to `document.body` since this will displace the whole page.

It turns out I need one regular element in the body to act as a shadow root:

```js
    const shadowHost = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(shadowHost);
    const shadow = shadowHost.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
```

But how can I protect this shadow root from being influenced by the css or js of the website?

Comment: Why not outright use a web component?

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

shadowRoots are not styled by global CSS, **unless they are *inheritable styles***

- https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/

`mode:"closed"` has nothing to do with CSS, it just doesn't publish the shadowRoot in `element.shadowRoot`, making it **impossible** to access the shadow DOM from the outside.

> When the mode of a shadow root is "closed", the shadow root’s implementation internals are inaccessible and unchangeable from JavaScript—in the same way the implementation internals of, for example, the `<video>` element are inaccessible and unchangeable from JavaScript.

```js
document.body
  .appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
  .attachShadow({mode:'closed'})
  .innerHTML = `<style>h1{color:green}</style><h1>Hello</h1><h2>Component</h2>`;
```

```html
<style>
  body {
    /* inheritable styles do style shadowRoots */
    font: 10px Arial;
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Applying a shadow DOM on a div is not turning it into a web component.

Comment: The term "Web Component" is a container term used incorrectly by almost everyone (including me). Many moons ago a Custom Element **without** shadowDOM was **not** to be  called a _Web Component_ either.

Comment: A custom element with shadow DOM is what I know and refer to as a web component.

Comment: Declarative shadow roots will make the `shadowRoot` available even if `mode: 'closed'` was picked: https://web.dev/declarative-shadow-dom/

Comment: I'm not sure about the last comment tho. Originally that is what they announced will be a forced consequence of declarative shadow DOM; I couldn't find that any more in the current explainer.

Comment: That is a choice. I stick to (Web Component) technologies supported by **all four** WHATWG members; and try no to spread rumours which are basicallly (yet again) Chromium only parties.